# Boolean result shows FALSE, should return TRUE

Tags: r, boolean

If `[list1$b]` exists, how come the boolean value is `FALSE` ?. See step-4 in below code. Due to value `FALSE`, the if statement will not be executed.

**Other observation:** I also noticed that during second run of the total script, the script states that 'a is missing in list1. Adding a', even though [list1$a] does exist.

**Wanted behavior/result:** If `[list1$b]` exists set boolean to `TRUE` and run the `if statement`. Also, in second round of total script, [list1$a] should detect that [list1$a] exists.

```
##########
# Step-1 #
##########
# Create list [list1] if missing.
if (!exists('list1')) {
  list1 <- list()
}

##########
# Step-2 #
##########
# Add variable [b] in list [list1].
list1$b <- 1

##########
# Step-3 #
##########
# Create variable [a] in list [list1] if missing.
if (!'a' %in% list1)  {
  print ('a is missing in list1. Adding a')
  list1$a <- 2
}

##########
# Step-4 #
##########
# Execute only print, if variable [b] in list [list1] exists. 
# Note! Even though variable [b] in list [list1] exists, the boolean result is FALSE.
if ('b' %in% list1)  {
  print ('b exists in list1. Do nothing')
}

# Print-out boolean result of Step-4:
boolean.result.of.step.four <- ('b' %in% list1)
print (paste0('Boolean result of step-4: ', boolean.result.of.step.four))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'b'` is the name of the object in `list1`. `%in%` matches values in a vector of values.

If you'd create `list1` as a list including the value `'b'`, your condition would be `TRUE`. See:

```
list1 <- list('b')
> 'b' %in% test1
[1] TRUE
```

In your situation, you can match `'b'` with the vector `names(list1)`. Therefore use `'b' %in% names(list1)` in your `if`-condition to make it work.